# Beginning Image Classification?

Tags: software-recommendations, references, image-classification

I'm a beginner with remote sensing and have the task of creating a land use/land cover map of a region in India from IRS imagery. I've never performed an image classification before, although I do have some pretty solid experience working with raster data in ArcMap.

While I've done a lot of reading on image classification (supervised and unsupervised), I'm still a little lost on where exactly to begin and what software would be the best to use (I do know that ArcMap has an image classification toolbar).

If someone could point me in the right direction on how to get started on this, or lead me to any good resources it would be a massive help!

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  As a new user please take the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Unfortunately, you've got a number of questions in this question, and they're all either too *broad* or *opinion-based* to fit the "focused question, best answer" model used here.

Answer (score 1):

Arc GIS have introduced the image classification tool in version 10. If You want to classify the images using Arc Map. Check this [tutorial of the tool](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/09/image-classification-toolbar-introduced-at-arcgis-10/).

You may also use other softwares like ENVI or ERDAS IMAGINE for this purpose.
For the case of ENVI [this tutorial](https://www.harrisgeospatial.com/docs/classificationtutorial.html) guides you through the process and can perform both supervised and unsupervised classifications.

Similarly you may also use other opensource softwares to perform. [This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/36736/what-is-the-best-open-source-software-package-for-remote-sensing) thread gives very good source of softwares that are available for classification.